# When writing JSP code and running on tomcat server, nothing displays

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Im really new to this but, when Im writing a really simple JSP site, it just displays a blank page. And when I inspect the site, the code doesnt show up.

[This is my JSP file called BookList.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5XC7.png)

[My Servlet File, called ControllerServlet.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjktJ.png)

[What appears in my browser and when I inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDOse.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet:

Use the `@Override` annotation also for interface methods, where it is optional.
It helps finding wrong method signatures (=unreached methods).

A servlet object is reused, serialized to disk, and so on. Hence modified
*fields* are evil, and generally I would refrain from fields. For a fixed list, like here, it is possible, but I would do it using the life cycle methods:

```
private List<String> bookTitles;

@Override
public void init() {
    // You might access the servlet config here.
    bookTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(bookTitles,
        "Faith in Fakes: Travels in Hyperreality",
        "Null-A",
        "Wasp");
}

@Override
... doGet(...) ... {
    log("book_titles are passed: " + bookTitles);
    ...
}
```

JSP:

ISO-8859-1 is the standard HTTP encoding, Latin-1.
Nowadays and prescribed in HTML5 (you are using) that is interpreted
as the extended Windows Latin-1, Windows-1252 (even on Mac/Linux).
So comma like quotes and some other symbols may be displayed.

```
... charset=Windows-1252 ...  pageEncoding="Windows-1252"

${requestScope.book_titles}
```